# "CRS object has comment, which is lost in output" in krige

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, kriging, r-stars

I am trying to krige for water quality dataset with Latitude, longitude which using CRS("+init=epsg:4326").

```
GGT <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Data/newdata2019.csv")
coordinates(GGT) = ~Lon+Lat
GGT <- st_as_sf(GGT)
st_crs(GGT) <- 4326

GGTgrid <- readOGR('C:/Users/user/Desktop/FisheryScience/Data/Maps/GGTgrid.shp')
GGTgrid1 <- st_as_stars(GGTgrid, crs = 4326)
st_crs(GGTgrid1) <- 4326
```

[image]

-This is what GGT dataset looks like

```
vario <- variogram(log(DO_S)~1, GGT)
model_GGT <- fit.variogram(vario, model=vgm(psill = 1, model= 'Sph', range= 200, nugget =1))
plot(vario, model = model_GGT)
```

[image]
-It seems to work fine by here

Then it shows error when I run the code block below

```
krige_result <- krige(formula = log(DO_S)~1, GGT, GGTgrid1, model = model_GGT)
```

with long lines of error

> Warning message in proj4string(obj): 
> "CRS object has comment, which is lost in output"Warning message in proj4string(obj): 
> "CRS object has comment, which is lost in output"Warning message in proj4string(obj):

Answer (score 0):

The warnings you get are indicating that your work may be affected by the change introduced with PROJ 6 (and GDAL 3), adopted by R-spatial and rspatial. You can get all the details using this two links:

https://rgdal.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/CRS_projections_transformations.html

https://r-spatial.org/r/2020/03/17/wkt.html

To make these warning messages disappear, you just have to use objects of type `sf` and `stars` (by installing/loading the packages of the same names) which take into account these recent changes. So, I suggest you use the following few lines of code at the beginning of your script to replace your first six lines of code. This will give you two objects (i.e. GGT of type `sf` and GGTgrid1 of type `stars`) :

```r
GGT <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Data/newdata2019.csv")
coordinates(GGT) = ~Lon+Lat
GGT <- st_as_sf(GGT)
st_crs(GGT) <- 4326

GGTgrid <- readOGR('C:/Users/user/Desktop/maps/GGTgrid.shp')
coordinates(GGTgrid) <- ~x+y
GGTgrid1 <- st_as_stars(GGTgrid1, crs = 4326)
st_crs(GGTgrid1) <- 4326
```

It is easier for me to work on real data than to work "virtually" with the name of your objects as I don't have your original files. So I prefer to show you how to proceed for your analysis with the "meuse" data contained in the `sp` package.

By analogy with the reprex I give you, I think you should be able to manage with your own files. And you will see, no more warning message will appear :-)

Please, find below my reprex.

**Reprex**

- Loading the library and the data

```r
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(gstat)

data(meuse)                # loading the data (equivalent of your csv file)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y  # you already know this step ;-)

# Just a look to the class of original data 
class(meuse)
#> [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"                # "meuse" is an object of class 'sp'


data(meuse.grid)           # loading the data (equivalent of your shp file)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y

# Just a look to the class of original data 
class(meuse.grid)
#> [1] "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"                # "meuse" is an object of class 'sp'
```

- Converting the `meuse` data into `sf` object and the `meuse.grid` data into `stars` object

```r
# Convert 'sp' object 'meuse' (i.e. SpatialPointsDataFrame) into 'sf' object
meuse <-  st_as_sf(meuse)

class(meuse) 
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"    # meuse is indeed of class 'sf'

# Convert 'sp' object 'meuse.grid' (i.e. SpatialPixelDataFrame) into 'stars' object
meuse.grid <-  st_as_stars(meuse.grid)

class(meuse.grid) 
#> [1] "stars"                       # meuse.grid is indeed of class 'stars'
```

- Compute and plot the variogram

```r
vario <-  variogram(log(zinc)~1, meuse)
model_meuse <-  fit.variogram(vario, model = vgm(psill = 1, model = "Sph", range = 200, nugget = 1))
plot(vario, model = model_meuse)
```

[image]

- Krige and plot predictions and variances

```r
krige_result <- krige(formula = log(zinc)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = model_meuse)
#> [using ordinary kriging]
class(krige_result)
#> [1] "stars"
krige_result
#> stars object with 2 dimensions and 2 attributes
#> attribute(s):
#>                  Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
#> var1.pred  4.77655207 5.2376428 5.5728908 5.7072284 6.1717618 7.4399908 5009
#> var1.var   0.08549102 0.1372838 0.1621815 0.1853301 0.2116141 0.5002793 5009
#> dimension(s):
#>   from  to offset delta refsys point values x/y
#> x    1  78 178440    40     NA    NA   NULL [x]
#> y    1 104 333760   -40     NA    NA   NULL [y]
```

```r
plot(krige_result[1]) # plot predictions
```

[image]

```r
plot(krige_result[2]) # plot variances
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Let me know if it works. If so, please consider marking this response as accepted. If not, please tell me what is the problem you are experiencing. Cheers

Comment: Thanks lovalery for your help and time, it gives error on plotting GGTgrid **(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**  Also for code `PbSph <- krige(DO_S~1, GGT, GGTgrid, model = sph.fit)`, it prings long line of error **"CRS object has comment, which is lost in output"Warning message in proj4string(obj):** . `PbKrig <- autoKrige(DO_S~1, GGT, GGTgrid1)` this code prints **Error in autoKrige(DO_S ~ 1, GGT, GGTgrid1): 
Invalid input objects: input_data or data_variogram not of class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame'.** error.

Comment: O.K.  sorry, I misguided you. I have just edited my answer above. Read it again from the beginning because I modified the few lines of code I gave you the first time. You will see, I did a commented reprex which should normally allow you to succeed in your analysis. If you still have any difficulties, don't hesitate to ask me. If everything works properly, please mark the answer as accepted. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and help on this and I am sorry for late reply as I was given another task to finish urgently. I tried the steps that you kindly explained and got errors on the krige function. Please have a look on the question.

Comment: No worries about the delay. I understand that you may be busy with other tasks. Thanks for the new information in your question. To be honest, I don't quite understand at this moment why R is still returning this warning message. That said, this is a warning message, not an error message. So, did you get a result at the end? And if so, does it seem correct?

Comment: Besides, I do have a few questions to try to narrow down the problem: what libraries are loaded in your R session? What is the version of the different packages? Did you try to run the reprex I provided? If so, does R return the same warning message or does the code run correctly from start to finish? Thank you in advance for this additional information.